# Dutch Locale: Input (number) amount formatting

Tags: html, input, angular5, inputformatter

I am developing an applicaiton in Angular5 where I need to develop a form which will be used by user to input amounts. As users are from the Netherlands, They are used to Dutch currency format. *This means, 10.50 is displayed as 10,50 in Dutch locate*

Is there a in-build component which I can use for input of Dutch formatted currency. User should be able to use **","** as decimal point.

When user enters vat amount and nett amount in respective input boxes, I want to show calculated gross amount (netAMount+vatAmount) in third input box

Thanks in advance.

regards,
Venky

Answer (score 0):

Do you know numeral.js?

Probably is what you looking for.

In my opinion the best solution.

And you have support for a lot of langagues

http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: Although I had to do lot of work-around, this is best possible library for me. Thanks a ton!!